# Explode then Choose the Correct Email?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string which looks like this:

email@domain1.com|email@domain5.com

I need only the email matching 'domain5'.

```
$domain_needle  = 'domain5.com';
$employer_email = 'email@domain1.com|email@domain5.com';
$employer_email = explode('|', $employer_email);
```

How can I pick the array member which has the domain5?

Using substr_count()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$domain_needle  = 'domain5.com';
$employer_email = 'email@domain1.com|email@domain5.com';
$employer_email = explode('|', $employer_email);

foreach($employer_email as $email){
    if(strpos($email, $domain_needle) !== false){
        $employer_email = $email;
        break;
    }
}

echo $employer_email;
```

Comment: I was in the midst of replying with an almost identical answer.  You could do it in a few different ways but this one is good.

Comment: @SubstanceD, sure, it can be done in many ways, but I think this one is simplest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_grep`:

```
$result = preg_grep("/$domain_needle/", $employer_email);
```

Example, with `array_shift` to extract the first value from the returned array:

```
$domain_needle  = 'domain5.com';
$employer_email = 'email@domain1.com|email@domain5.com';
$employer_email = explode('|', $employer_email);
print array_shift(preg_grep("/$domain_needle/", $employer_email));
```

Outputs:

```
email@domain5.com
```